# Is this particular statement a phrase or a clause?

Tags: phrases, subordinate-clauses

The difference between clauses and phrases has been extensively discussed ([here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133853/the-difference-between-a-clause-and-a-phrase), [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/what-is-the-difference-between-a-phrase-and-a-clause), and likely elsewhere). And as Dusty has said, [“The short answer [is that] clauses contain a subject and its verb, while phrases do not.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5364/114799)

In a recent comment (found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263076/comma-usage-and-maintain-succinctness)), I noted that the questioner’s sentence—“The day I was born, Granny died”—was formed by two *clauses*. However, phoog responded that ["the day I was born" is not a clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263076/comma-usage-and-maintain-succinctness?noredirect=1#comment578393_263076), but rather (I presume) a phrase.

Is this true? If I am to judge by Dusty’s short answer—that a clause contains a subject and a verb—then “the day I was born” checks out as a clause. My understanding is that “the day I was born” is a subordinate clause—or, in the words of Wikipedia, [“a clause that provides an independent clause with additional information, but which cannot stand alone as a sentence.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)

Unless you think they are necessary to the meaning of your answer, I do not need definitions of phrases and clauses. Rather, I am looking for a definitive answer—phrase or clause—and proof as to how or why you came to that conclusion.

**EDIT:** I deleted this question because I felt as though it had been answered on the original post by phoog. He responded to my comment, noting that ["[*the day I was born is*] an adverbial noun phrase. It has no predicate, as a clause must. The clause I was born modifies the day, but the fact that the phrase contains a clause doesn't make it a clause."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263076/comma-usage-and-maintain-succinctness?noredirect=1#comment578631_263076)

However, Araucaria commented on another post of mine, asking me to reopen this question. He states, "The linked-to answer is a bit misleading (to say the least), but your question is excellent, and is a very good example for people to investigate!" That said, I have reopened the question and am curious to hear any and all opinions and/or interpretations of phoog's explanation.

Comment: What type of construction an expression is will usually depend on the context. For example, the construction *"the day I was born"* could sometimes be a NP, e.g. *"My older sister's worst day of her life was [the day (that) I was born]"*. Now as to something like: *“The day I was born, Granny died”*, then you'll probably also want to consider if that is a fronting of a NP, where the default order might be: *“Granny died the day I was born”*. But anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The day I was born, Granny died”

Inverted --->  "Granny died the day I was born.”

In full ---->  "Granny died *on* the day *that* I was born.”

Same structure ---->  "Granny died on Tuesday.”

**Answer**

"the day I was born" is a noun phrase.

"I was born" is a clause.